# Testing with Django: how to display all characters when using assertEqual with json object?

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I'm testing django-rest-framework. When I `POST` some content in `json` format and want to test if it was posted correctly I try to get the object posted with

```
resp_get = self.client.get(self.url)
```

and test with `assertEqual` (`json` format):

```
self.assertEqual(
            json.loads(resp_get.content.decode('utf8')),
            [
                {
                    'id': researcher.id,
                    'first_name': researcher.first_name,
                    'surname': researcher.surname,
                    'email': researcher.email,
                    'studies': [],
                    'nes_id': researcher.nes_id,
                    'owner': researcher.owner.username
                }
            ]
        )
```

As comparing results false, I get an `AssertionError` with following message

```
AssertionError: {'id': 1, 'first_name': 'João Maria', 'su[102 chars]ab1'} != [{'id': 1, 'first_name': 'João Maria', 's[104 chars]b1'}]
```

I'd like to know if is someway possible to get entire `json` object compared in both sides, as `AssertionError` returns the object compacted: `su[102 chars]ab1`, and `s[104 chars]b1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `assertDictEqual`

```
self.assertDictEqual(item1, item2)
```